# Tic - Tac - Toe... each() not a function

Tags: javascript, jquery, foreach, each, tic-tac-toe

```
function whoWonGame(){

const winnerSection = ['row1', 'row2', 'row3','column1', 'column2', 'column3', 'dag1', 'dag2' ];
let winner = null;
winnerSection.each((section) => {

  let match = true;

  for(let i = 1; i <= 2; i++ ){

   $(`${section}`).each((div) => {

      if(div.hasClass(`player${i}`)){

          match = false;
      }
    })

    if(match){

      winner = `player${i}`;

    }

    return winner;
  }


})

}
```

I get an error saying winnerSection.each is not a function. How could that be?

Comment: It means that `${section}` is undefined.

Comment: use forEach instead or jquery $.each

Comment: Apart from the `each` issue, are the elements in `winnerSection` IDs? Classes? You need a `.` or `#` before `${section}`, since `row1` etc. are certainly not element names.

Answer (score 1):

it's `Array.prototype.forEach`, not `each`.

Comment: jQuery's [**`.each()`**](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.each/) is a perfectly valid function.

Comment: I don't use jQuery, but it seems this function should be called like this?

`$.each(arrayObject, callback)`

Answer (score 1):

winnerSection is not a jQuery object. To iterate over an array using .each you must do so:

```
$.each(winnerSection, function(index, section) {
});
```

See documentation: 
http://api.jquery.com/jquery.each/

or use the javascript foreach function: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach

```
winnerSection.forEach(function(section, index) {
});
```

Caution: the order of parameters of both functions.

--- UPDATE ---

I delete the full code, because I don't have enough information to infere the solution. I limit the answer to the first error/question.

Comment: This is almost correct. Only ``$(`${section}`)`` isn’t selecting any elements.

Comment: Yes @Xufox, it's true, I haven't evaluated yet but ${} it's not a jquery selector till I know. Solomon mentions only winnerSection.each, and that's what i fix.

Comment: Well, `${}` is part of template literal syntax. That’s not really the point. The problem is that these will evaluate to e.g. `$("row1")`, where it should likely be `$(".row1")`.

Comment: @Xufox, I delete the code, because without more information on question it's impossible to post the solution, and SO isn't a code trivial! :)

Answer (score -1):

winnerSection is not extending jQuery. Try with this:

$(winnerSection).each(.......);